# How to get the correct intersection coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Created two squares. Applied to both **BoxCollider2D**. I added a **RigidBody2D** to the red one and turned off the simulation in it so that there was no extrusion. When I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, I shift the red square by `1` along the **X** axis. A collision occurs. With the help of `OnCollisionEnter2D` I read and output to the console the coordinates of the intersection points. There are always two of them. In the picture, I selected them and signed the coordinates `(0; 0.7)` and `(0.5; 1)`. But if you look at their calculated coordinates in the console, it turns out that they are `(0; 0.85)` and `(0.52; 0.85)`. If we compare the x-coordinates, then they are approximately equal. But the Y-coordinates of both `points = 0.85`. And this is just the middle between the Y-coordinates in the picture. Tell me why is this happening? And how to get the correct intersection coordinates?

[image]